# how to extract correct id from json with jsonpath Expression in Gatling

Tags: json, scala, gatling

I'm using Gatling to test API's and I have to extract an ID from a JSON and store it in a variable, but Gatling doesn't support this: `"$.[?(@.name == 'manage-account')].id"` How can I find the ID that belongs to 'manage-account'?

The JSON looks like this:

```
    {
  "realmRoles" : [ {
    "id" : "2253a9b4-bc1e",
    "name" : "offline_access",
    "description" : "${role_offline-access}",
    "composite" : false,
    "clientRole" : false,
    "containerId" : "sp"
  }, {
    "id" : "313d800c",
    "name" : "ua_authorization",
    "description" : "${role_ua_authorization}",
    "composite" : false,
    "clientRole" : false,
    "containerId" : "sp"
  } ],
  "clientRoles" : [ {
    "client" : {
      "id" : "37e4837b-8e77",
      "name" : "account"
    },
    "roles" : [ {
      "id" : "48abb872-dc25",
      "name" : "manage-account-links",
      "description" : "${role_manage-account-links}",
      "composite" : false,
      "clientRole" : true,
      "containerId" : "37e4837b-8e77e"
    }, {
      "id" : "a1fadc14-30c18",
      "name" : "manage-account",
      "description" : "${role_manage-account}",
      "composite" : true,
      "clientRole" : true,
      "containerId" : "37e4837b-8e77"
    } ]
  }, {
    "client" : {
      "id" : "ef80d8e9-5f9b",
      "name" : "realm-management"
    },
    "roles" : [ {
      "id" : "d1e35e29-b26e",
      "name" : "manage-users",
      "description" : "${role_manage-users}",
      "composite" : false,
      "clientRole" : true,
      "containerId" : "ef80d8e9-5f93"
    } ]
  }]
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsonPath currently lacks a proper spec, so syntax interpretation differs from one implementation to another.

Here, you should be using `$..*[?(@.name == 'manage-account')].id`: you want recursive descent (`..`) and match any node (`*`) that matches your filter.

If you want to stop suffering from those differences, I would recommend switching to JMESPath instead, see our [blog](https://gatling.io/2019/07/31/introducing-jmespath-support/). The main thing JMESPath lacks comparing to JsonPath is recursive descent, which is convenient but has poor performance. You have to specify the full path.